# Вывод результата метода в другой метод

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, методы

Подскажите пожалуйста, могу ли я подставить возвращаемые результаты из функций `gender()` и `age_check()` в функцию `show_info()`?
Например я создаю экземпляр со следующими аргументами:

```
person1 = People('m', 20)
```

И я хочу получить в строке `return (f"That is {self.its_gender}, and person is {self.age}")` такой вывод:
`That is Man and person is Adult`

Что для этого необходимо изменить?

```
class People:
    def __init__(self, its_gender, age):
        self.its_gender = its_gender
        self.age = age

    def show_info(self):
        return (f"That is {self.its_gender}, and person is {self.age}")

    def gender(self):
        if self.its_gender == "m":
            return ("Man")
        elif self.its_gender == 'f':
            return ("Woman")

    def age_check(self):
        if self.age > 18:
            return ("Adult")
        elif self.age <= 18:
            return ("Young")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо написать эту строку используя в подстановках вызовы методов, вот так:

```
return (f"That is {self.gender()}, and person is {self.age_check()}")
```

Comment: Спасибо, понял!